# A ruby method to replace "="

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to eliminate "=" sign for a particular reason. It might looks like this:

```
cat_that_has_name("Kelly").as(:kelly)
kelly.do_something
```

The "as" method here is used to generate a method "kelly" that reference my cat. Could anyone help me with this?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update:**

Jorg was right, I've add a simple test to demonstrate my intention:

```
require "test/unit"

class AsTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @cats = ["Kelly", "Tommy"]
  end

  def teardown
  end

  def test_as
    kelly1 =  get_cat("Kelly")
    get_cat("Kelly").as(:kelly2)
    assert_equal(kelly1.object_id, kelly2.object_id)
  end

  private
  def get_cat(name)
    @cats.each do |cat|
      if cat.to_s==name
        return cat
      end
    end
    return nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Which particular '=' did you want to eliminate, I can't see a single one in your example?

Comment: If your code is the "after", would the "before" be something like `kelly = cat_that_has_name("Kelly") ; kelly.do_something`?

Comment: Are you wanting to avoid the possibility of `=` being mixed up with `==`, or are you worried about assignment methods that go awry (`foo = 2` versus `self.foo = 2`) or just curious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of hard to figure out what you actually want. If you want some sensible answers, you will have to provide a complete code example of what you want to achieve (for example, the code you posted is missing definitions for the `cat_that_has_name` and `so_something` methods). You will also need to post a complete specification of what exactly you expect the `as` method to do, with usage examples and ideally also with a testsuite. After all, how do we know if our answer is correct if you haven't defined what "correct" means?

The best I could decipher from your cryptic question is something like this:

```
class Object
  def as(name)
    s = self
    Object.send(:define_method, name) { s }
    Object.send(:private, name)
  end
end
```

But there is no way of knowing whether this works, because if I try to run your code example, I get a `NoMethodError` for `cat_that_has_name` and another `NoMethodError` for `so_something`.

Note also that your question is self-inconsistent: in your subject line you ask about a method to replace `=` (i.e. creating variables) but in your question you talk about creating *methods*, which would mean that you are looking for a replacement for `def` and not for `=`. Again, it would be much easier to answer correctly if there were a testsuite.

Comment: @eric2323223: Hey, my code actually passes the test. I didn't expect that.